# How to link checkboxes in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-link

```
* Core
- [X] CS 501
- [X] CS 502
- [X] CS 503 
- [ ] ORG 601 [Fall 2021]
- [ ] ORG 602 [Fall 2021]
- [ ] ORG 603 [Fall 2021]

* Schedule
** Spring 2021
- [X] CS 501
- [X] CS 502
- [X] CS 503 

** Fall 2021
- [ ] ORG 601
- [ ] ORG 602
- [ ] ORG 603
```

Link checkboxes from the `Core` header so that toggling `ORG 601` anywhere, toggles it everywhere

```
* Core
- [X] CS 501
- [X] CS 502
- [X] CS 503 
- [ ] ORG 601 [Fall 2021]
- [ ] ORG 602 [Fall 2021]
- [ ] ORG 603 [Fall 2021]

* Schedule
** Spring 2021
- [X] CS 501
- [X] CS 502
- [X] CS 503 

** Fall 2021
- [X] ORG 601
- [ ] ORG 602
- [ ] ORG 603
```

->

```
* Core
- [X] CS 501
- [X] CS 502
- [X] CS 503 
- [X] ORG 601 [Fall 2021]
- [ ] ORG 602 [Fall 2021]
- [ ] ORG 603 [Fall 2021]

* Schedule
** Spring 2021
- [X] CS 501
- [X] CS 502
- [X] CS 503 

** Fall 2021
- [X] ORG 601
- [ ] ORG 602
- [ ] ORG 603
```

**BONUS:** Have `[Fall 2021]` get inserted automatically when linked under that header.

Comment: There are no Org mode facilities for doing something like this - AFAIK. So the only possibility I see is purely text matching.

Comment: Bummer, would be cool, no?

Comment: you can definitely do this with a bespoke text matching scheme. The current layout would require a pattern to match "ORG 601" and "ORG 601 [Fall 2021]" so that presumably checking either one makes the other one change too?